# Fresh installation without losing /home directory?

Tags: home-directory, re-installation

I am running ubuntu 11.10 32bit. I have separate `/` and `/home` partitions. I want to go back to Ubuntu 10.04. How can I do this without losing my `/home` partition. Basically I want to save my preferences and all the settings I have saved, my emails accounts and other stuff. I have also setup github and bitbucket setup in this /home partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While installing , install Ubuntu in "/" partition as usual and *dont* format /home partition. It will remain as it is <strike>(By the way I made the assumption that by "/home" you mean your home directory)</strike>

And one more thing that you need to do is it should be indicated to the installer that you want to mount that particular partition under `/home`.

Answer (score 2):

I do it the other way around. I have a single partition, but while freshly installing a new version of Linux, I just copy the `/home` and paste it after a fresh install.

And voila all settings are resorted back as my old installation.

WARNING : It sometimes can cause problem with certain applications. eg. recently I reverted back to 10.04 from the latest 11.10, which caused rhythmbox to cause some anomalous behavior, since it couldn't save the media library.